# Is there a conversion method that takes a char and produces a ConsoleKey?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder if there is any helper class in the .NET framework (or somewhere else) that converts chars to ConsoleKey enums.

```
e.g 'A' should become ConsoleKey.A
```

Before someone asks why I would want to do that. I want to write a helper that takes a string (e.g. 'Hello World') and converts it into a sequence of ConsoleKeyInfo objects. I need this for some crazy unit tests where I'm mocking user input.

I'm just a little tired of creating glue code on my own so I thought, maybe there is already a way to convert a char to a ConsoleKey enum?

**For completeness here is what seems to work great so far**

```
    public static IEnumerable<ConsoleKeyInfo> ToInputSequence(this string text)
    {
        return text.Select(c =>
                               {
                                   ConsoleKey consoleKey;
                                   if (Enum.TryParse(c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), true, out consoleKey))
                                   {
                                       return new ConsoleKeyInfo(c, consoleKey, false, false, false);
                                   }
                                   else if (c == ' ')
                                       return new ConsoleKeyInfo(' ', ConsoleKey.Spacebar, false, false, false);
                                   return (ConsoleKeyInfo?) null;
                               })
            .Where(info => info.HasValue)
            .Select(info => info.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
```

Comment: Is this for characters and digits only? You cannot have a 1-to-1 mapping, because `ConsoleKey` does not distinguish character casing, and does not contain most other ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes that's true. Right know I have it only for characters and whitespace. I will add period and comma, too. The casing doesn't matter because this information will be preserved in the ConsoleKeyInfo object directly as a char.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
char a = 'A';
ConsoleKey ck;
Enum.TryParse<ConsoleKey>(a.ToString(), out ck);
```

So:

```
string input = "Hello World";
input.Select(c => (ConsoleKey)Enum.Parse(c.ToString().ToUpper(), typeof(ConsoleKey));
```

or

```
.Select(c =>
    {
        return Enum.TryParse<ConsoleKey>(a.ToString().ToUpper(), out ck) ?
            ck :
            (ConsoleKey?)null;
    })
.Where(x => x.HasValue) // where parse has worked
.Select(x => x.Value);
```

Also `Enum.TryParse()` has [an overload to ignore case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx).

Comment: `c.ToString().ToLower()` - aren't they all *uppercase*?

Comment: @minitech: Sure, they are, just a typo.

Comment: Thanks, `ToUpper` will work better. In the last example, `Select` should also take two generic parameter types, `a` should be changed to `c`. But I would rather let an exception be thrown than swallow characters, since it may make it less useful for testing this way IMHO.

Comment: @Groo: Thanks, you're right, I haven't noticed these mistakes initially, corrected.

Comment: Oh no, Enum.TryParse...that's so obvious. Sure that works! Thank you!

Comment: Just one thing. I'm sure you meant to put `ConsoleKey ck` (the declaration for the out parameter) into that function body of the last snippet.

Comment: @Christoph: That's up to. You can declare it either out of the lambda's scope or into it.

Comment: Yes, sure. Just feels odd to declare it outside. Especially as the snippets seem to be meant to all work independently.

Comment: It does not work for back slash or even space. Provided example "Hello world" does not work either because of exception "Must specify valid information for parsing in the string."

Answer (score 1):

If you using .NET4 or later you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx). and [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.80%29) is avalable for .NET2 and later.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is [A-Z] & [0-9] OP can use it

It might work because ConsoleKey is an [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey.aspx)

so you can do soemthing like this

```
char ch = 'A';
ConsoleKey ck = (ConsoleKey) ch;
```

Comment: I doubt it will work. For instance `(ConsoleKey)"BrowserSearch"` must throw an exception.

Comment: @abatishchev please see my updated answer I started get -1 before I finished the entire answer.

Comment: @abatishchev Down voters never give the reason when asked and never reply back so it cannot be you :)

Comment: But it does work for digits. Cannot use `Enum.Parse` for digits because they are named `D0` through `D9`. +1